# How to start a rails app automatically in user enviroment after system reboot?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, rvm, startupscript

Rails apps on server are started automatically via `/etc/rc.local`, i.e.:

```
thin start -p 8000 -c /usr/local/src/app1/curr -d -e production
```

In addition to above, I'd like to start some apps in a particular user's environment. Typically those are apps in development or UAT stage. For example, there is an app `logger` in:

```
/home/john/apps/logger/curr
```

which I usually start it as:

```
cd /home/john/apps/logger/curr
rvm 1.9.3
thin start -p 9001 -d
```

How can I specify an auto-started script such that after a system reboots, the `logger` app can be started without human intervention, in a certain `rvm` environment (ruby version + gemsets)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create wrapper, using aliases also help, follow details here http://rvm.io/integration/init-d and the example init.d script in RVM => https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/blob/master/contrib/unicorn_init.sh